# set video to html video tag - cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

My app is a cordova hybrid Windows phone 8.1 app.

I am capturing a video with media-capture plugin and getting the video url in my callback which is something like this:

/VideoCache/Video-7c5eb8ae-5c3d-48ee-9f3b-0805e81ebc06.mp4

How can I set this video to an html video tag.

I created a super simple project to reproduce this error and shared on [onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A32C3B0B26B01F55!263&authkey=!ABgpyxFVH2QKIOk&ithint=file%2Czip)

here is the way I am calling it through javascript:

```
    // Called when capture operation is finished
//
    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
     var i, len;
    console.log("captureSuccess, mediaFiles: " + JSON.stringify(mediaFiles));
    console.log("mediaFiles.fullPath: " + mediaFiles[0].fullPath);

        //document.querySelector("#video1 > source").src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4";
    document.querySelector("#video1 > source").src = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;

}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// A button will call this function
//
function captureVideo() {
    // Launch device video recording application,
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit: 1 });
}
```

Comment: Hey, have you shared latest version of your project? I just downloaded it and extracted it. Here is what I saw - its a WP8 platform (which is Windows Phone 8 that builds XAP which is Silverlight based). It doesn't have the above code in index.js or any js file referenced. It is a Cordova CLI project as I don't see a VS project or solution file.  I would love to see the actual project if you have one to investigate the issue further.

Comment: thanks Subhag, yes it is correct you will find the solution at /VIdeoCordova/platforms/wp8

Comment: That is the native project. Can you point me to the JS file that contains the above code?

Comment: Also WP8, means its a Windows Phone 8 app not 8.1 app as you mention in your report heading above. Can you please clarify what exactly is your workflow here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an issue for windows phone 8.1. Seems the local video cannot be accessed within webbrowser control which is used by cordova for windows 8 and windows 8.1 silverlight app. Here the link on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fa66cbf-d67e-4c0a-bf2e-56262248d8df/set-video-to-html-video-tag-cordova-app?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova).

Answer (score 0):

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
videoElement.src = mediaFiles[0].fullPath; 
videoElement.load();
```

Comment: thanks Steve, but the message displayed is still invalid source instead of the video